# Performance of Skip and Take in Linq to Objects

Tags: c#, performance, linq, paging

"Searching for alternative functionalities for "Skip" and "Take" functionalities"

1 of the link says "Everytime you invoke Skip() it will have to iterate you collection from the beginning in order to skip the number of elements you desire, which gives a loop within a loop (n2 behaviour)"

Conclusion: For large collections, don’t use Skip and Take. Find another way to iterate through your collection and divide it.

In order to access last page data in a huge collection, can you please suggest us a way other than Skip and Take approach?

Comment: What is the type of the collection?

Comment: The iterating part is probably only true for `IEnumerable`, it would surprise me if `IList` didn't use an index for that.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Unfortunately no - [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,90ccdbd47b57182e)

Comment: @IvanStoev That's unexpected, keeping track of indexes yourself is the way to go then I guess

Comment: This optimization has been implemented in the corefx repo recently.

Comment: Jon Skeet touches on optimizing `Skip` for lists in part 23 of his Edulinq series and again in part 40: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/.  My take away is that he does not necessarily think it is a good idea.  Maybe.  In section 23 he kinds of waffles on the subject but in section 40 he seems to have concluded it is not a good idea.

Comment: @JasonBoyd that optimisation has in fact been done in corefx as usr said. The observable change was evaluated but deemed to be acceptable. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/4551

Comment: @JonHanna thanks for the linq.  That was a good read.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,90ccdbd47b57182e,references) for `Skip`, you can see it enumerates over **all** the items, even over the first n items you want to skip.
It's strange though, because several LINQ-methods have optimizations for collections, like `Count` and `Last`.
`Skip` apparently does not.

If you have an array or `IList<T>`, you use the indexer to truly skip over them:

```
for (int i = skipStartIndex; i < list.Count; i++) {
    yield return list[i];
}
```

Comment: Depends on the version. The current [.NET Core source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Skip.cs) is optimised for lists, the results of `OrderBy` and several other cases, with more improvements hopefully coming soon. Note that the current behaviour for `Skip()` on an `IList<T>` is close to what you have here.

Comment: Using skip is not at all efficient to fetch the last page data. It is taking almost 13 seconds to fetch the last 100 records out of 2 Lakh records.

Looking at the valuable comments, Can i conclude that We should not use Skip and Take for huge data.

No we are not using array and list. We have used deferred query (IEnumerable) for fetching the data from DB.

Answer (score 1):

Internally it is really correct:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)
{
  using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
  {
    while (count > 0 && enumerator.MoveNext())
      --count;
    if (count <= 0)
    {
      while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to skip for `IEnumerable<T>` then it works right. There are no other way except enumeration to get specific element(s). But you can write own extension method on `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IList<T>` (if this interface is implemented in collection used for your elements).

```
public static class IReadOnlyListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Skip<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> collection, int count)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            return null;

        return ICollectionExtensions.YieldSkip(collection, count);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> YieldSkip<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> collection, int count)
    {
        for (int index = count; index < collection.Count; index++)
        {
            yield return collection[index];
        }
    }
}
```

In addition you can implement it for `IEnumerable<T>` but check inside for optimization:

```
if (collection is IReadOnlyList<T>)
{
    // do optimized skip
}
```

Such solution is used a lot of where in Linq source code (but not in Skip unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your implementation, but it would make sense to use indexed arrays for the purpose, instead.